# TextView showing HexValue (0x0d0a) for CR LF in Android

Tags: android

While saving data from textview, CR LF is storing like hex value 0x0d0a. But while showing same data in another text view **which is inside list view**, not showing return space for 0x0d0a. Instead of that it is directly printing /0x0d0a. Any help here. 
Thanks in advance. -- Raghav

Comment: Show some code. There might be a problem on the way you are extracting text from the Textview.

Comment: code is simple--> textview.setText(MyTextData);

Comment: Only change is when I am putting this textview in list view, it is behaving like this. Else it works fine.

Comment: Whats MyTextData ? With some debugging, you should quickly find out the problem.

Comment: MyTextData is String text which is something like this ("sample test/0x0d0a"). UI wise it is having return after "sample test".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got resolved today. Text view shows return space only for \n. Replacing /0x0d0a with \n solved the issue. Thanks !!